# Java spring не может найти зависимость

Tags: java, spring, maven

Учусь создавать web app. На офф.сайте spring нашел зависимости и попытался создать контроллер

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
@Controller
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("main", "Main Page");
        model.addAttribute("world", "world");
        return "main";
    }
}
```

подсвечивает как ошибку в классе Controller запись с импортам

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
```

Вот ошибка при выполнении

```
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
webapp/controllers/Controller.java:[3,1] webapp.controllers.Controller is already defined in this compilation unit
webapp/controllers/Controller.java:[7,2] incompatible types: webapp.controllers.Controller cannot be converted to java.lang.annotation.Annotation
2 errors 
-------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  8.475 s
Finished at: 2020-06-16T22:33:27+03:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project WebApp: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
webapp/controllers/Controller.java:[3,1] webapp.controllers.Controller is already defined in this compilation unit
webapp/controllers/Controller.java:[7,2] incompatible types: webapp.controllers.Controller cannot be converted to java.lang.annotation.Annotation
-> [Help 1]
```

Сам pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!--  lookup parent from repository  -->
</parent>
    
<groupId>com.elvpr</groupId>
<artifactId>WebApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>WebApp</name>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>        
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <jakartaee>8.0</jakartaee>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

 <build>                  
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                                <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

скажите может какой зависимости не хватает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы назвали класс одинаково с интерфейсом из Spring:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
```

Из за чего Java не может достать реализацию Spring, потому что постоянно натыкается на ваш класс:

```
webapp/controllers/Controller.java:[3,1] webapp.controllers.Controller is already defined in this compilation unit
```

Чтобы исправить эту проблему, просто переименуйте название вашего класса.

Вообще, называть класс контроллера `Controller` плохая практика, лучше указывать область видимости для названия данного класса, например: `HomeController` или `MainController`.